# Can I create a 'reserved word' for a commonly used string in an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is not a calculation or a function,  it is simply a command I have to add often which is difficult to remember.

I am often running queries on data across two databases (one old, one new) so I have to add "collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" wherever values of one are being compared with values of the other.

For example...

```
...where db1.transactions.accountnumber = db2.clients.accountnumber collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Is there a way to create something like a 'reserved word' for this, so that I could type something like the following...

```
where db1.transactions.accountnumber = db2.clients.accountnumber coll
```

where 'coll' is the replacement for 'collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=0) (free) has snippets which may do what you want.

We use SQL prompt too which has the same.

FYI: Have you considered `COLLATE Database_Default` which coerces collation to the current DB?

Comment: I downloaded the tool pack, then started downloading SP2 which it needs...  Then I saw your edit.  database_default does work.  much easier to remember.  Thanks :).     The tool pack looks like it might be useful for other things so I'll carry on with the sp2 upgrade.